# Transfering the latest data from Redshift to dynamoDB by AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I'm new to dynamoDB and AWS Glue and I'm trying to transfer data from Redshift Cluster to DynamoDB tables by using AWS Glue, but I want to keep **only** the most recent data from Cluster table.

As I understand, dropping the entire dynamoDB table and re-creating it is the logical idea. But if I do this, does that mean I need to create the dynamoDB tables by hand each time (?) The Glue jobs works weekly.

I tried Job Bookmarks, but the previous data was on the dynamoDB table:

[image]

An example of the Glue job, you can see in the code I'm trying to obtain the last snapshot_day:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue import DynamicFrame


def sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query, mapping, transformation_ctx) -> DynamicFrame:
    for alias, frame in mapping.items():
        frame.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView(alias)
    result = spark.sql(query)
    return DynamicFrame.fromDF(result, glueContext, transformation_ctx)


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node Redshift Cluster
RedshiftCluster_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="dbname",
    redshift_tmp_dir=args["TempDir"],
    table_name="tablename",
    transformation_ctx="RedshiftCluster_node1",
)

# Script generated for node SQL
SqlQuery0 = """
select * from vendor_info
WHERE snapshot_day = (SELECT MAX(snapshot_day) FROM vendor_info)

"""
SQL_node1660806425146 = sparkSqlQuery(
    glueContext,
    query=SqlQuery0,
    mapping={"vendor_info": RedshiftCluster_node1},
    transformation_ctx="SQL_node1660806425146",
)

# Script generated for node ApplyMapping
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=SQL_node1660806425146,
    mappings=[
        ("owning_buyer", "string", "owning_buyer", "string"),
        ("business_name", "string", "business_name", "string"),
        ("vendor_code", "string", "vendor_code", "string"),
        ("vendor_group_id", "int", "vendor_group_id", "int"),
        ("vendor_group_status_name", "string", "vendor_group_status_name", "string"),
        ("rand_id", "string", "rand_id", "string"),
        ("snapshot_day", "timestamp", "snapshot_day", "timestamp"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
)

# Script generated for node DynamoDB bucket
Datasink1 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=ApplyMapping_node2,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": "VENDOR_INFO",
        "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.0"
    }
)
job.commit()
```

This is the dynamoDB table structure, snapshot_day is the global secondary index. Should I try to change the partition key, sort key, secondy index? Or is there way to drop/truncate dynamoDB tables in AWS Glue jobs dynamically before transfering the data?

[image]

Thank you